# How to launch a daemon as root in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, root, daemon

I put my plist in /Library/LaunchAgents and my exexutive program in /usr/libexec and daemon statrs when system startup . But this daemon is owned by user . I try to put my plist in /Library/LauchDaemons but it's not working and daemon doesn't starts in system startup

I want to know how to make a daemon launch as root when system starts up.What additional jobs should I do to make a daemon launch as root ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `launchd` does exactly what you need.

Comment: What do you mean? What should I do? I can start a daemon with launchctl load coomand oon terminal . But the daemon lifetime is not over a restart . After the system is rebooted daemon is not launching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you put plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons you need to run command `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.plist`

See `man launchctl` for the -w flag (it does exactly what you need)

**Edit**: did you set the RunAtLoad key to true in your plist?

**Edit2**: I forgot, RunAtLoad has no influence on autolaunch, it is all bout Disabled key.

Comment: I try this but give me this error : launchctl: Dubious ownership on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mydaemon.plist
nothing found to load

Comment: They probably don't like you using com.apple in there.

Comment: You plist must be owned by root:wheel and have 0644 mod (-rw-r--r--)

Comment: What exactly should I do to make it work? I will be appreciated if you help me to solve this issue

Comment: `sudo chown root:wheel your.plist` and `sudo chmod 0644 your.plist`

Comment: Thanks you dear cody . The daemon starts up successfully but it launched as user not as root ? What is the mistake you think?

Comment: The daemon doesn't launch as root . I did all jobs you said but it doesn't launch as root !

Comment: why do you think it doesn't launch as root? Try two commands `sudo launchctl list | grep your_daemon_name` and `launchctl list | grep your_daemon_name`. Which one shows you your daemon?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Cody . I appreciate your help . It is solved . God bless you

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory where you put your plist, like this:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDeamon
```

This directory was read from Launchd before the startup of user.

Comment: I've tried using this solution right now, but since I've upgraded to El-Capitan I cannot move files to this directory. Is there a solution for this?